# Android Login - Account Authenticator vs Manual Authentication

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

I'm about to implement login along with user authentication in my app.

My first idea was to do it manually, register username and password with the server, get auth token, save it and use it in subsequent requests.

After googling around, I gathered that the correct way to do it on Android was using Account Authenticator. I've seen a few examples of it's implementation but I don't understand the advantage of doing it this way? Is it because I can have more than one account stored? Is it because of syncing issues? I'd appreciate if someone could explain this to me. It would probably make me understand the code for it better and why it's doing what it is.

Comment: This topic is dealt with in this site: http://www.digigene.com/android/accounts-in-android-part-one/

Answer (score 116, accepted):

> I can have more than one account stored?

Yes. See how  **Google** or **Facebook** do it.

> Is it because of syncing issues?

Yes, you need Account to use Synchronization mechanism like `SyncAdapter`

Why you should use `AccountAuthenticator`?

- Support of background synchronization mechanism like `SyncAdapter`;
- Standard way to authenticate users;
- Support different tokens;
- Account sharing with different privileges

What do you need to do?

1). Create `Authenticator`;

2). Create `Activity` for User Login;

3). Create `Service` to communicate with account.

## Terms.

[AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) - it manages account on device. Request auth tokens you should be using `AccountManager`.

[AbstractAccountAuthenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) - component for working with account types. It contains all logic for working with account(authorization, access rights etc.) One `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` may be used by different application(like Google account for Gmail, Calendar, Drive etc.)

[AccountAuthenticatorActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.html) - base `Activity`, for authorize/create account. `AccountManager` calls this account if it's necessary to identify account(Token doesn't exists or expired)

How all of it works? Look at the Image Below:

[image: android account management diagram]

## Steps.

1). Create `Authenticator`;

You need to extend `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` and override 7 methods:

- `Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String
  accountType)` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#editProperties(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20java.lang.String))
- `Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String
  accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle
  options)` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#addAccount(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle))
- `Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
  Account account, Bundle options)` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#confirmCredentials(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20android.accounts.Account,%20android.os.Bundle))
- `Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account
  account, String authTokenType, Bundle options)` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#getAuthToken(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))
- `String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType)` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#getAuthTokenLabel(java.lang.String))
- `Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
  Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options)` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#updateCredentials(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))
- `Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account
  account, String[] features)` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#hasFeatures(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String[]))

Example:

```
public class LodossAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = LodossAuthenticator.class.getSimpleName();

    private final Context mContext;

    public LodossAuthenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CustomServerAuthenticatorSigninActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Config.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
        intent.putExtra(Config.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
        intent.putExtra(Config.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);

        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        // If the caller requested an authToken type we don't support, then
        // return an error
        if (!authTokenType.equals(AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY) && !authTokenType.equals(AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS)) {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "invalid authTokenType");
            return result;
        }

        // Extract the username and password from the Account Manager, and ask
        // the server for an appropriate AuthToken.
        final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);
        String authToken = am.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

        // Lets give another try to authenticate the user
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            final String password = am.getPassword(account);
            if (password != null) {
                try {
                    authToken = sServerAuthenticate.userSignIn(account.name, password, authTokenType);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // If we get an authToken - we return it
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
            return result;
        }

        // If we get here, then we couldn't access the user's password - so we
        // need to re-prompt them for their credentials. We do that by creating
        // an intent to display our AuthenticatorActivity.
        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
        intent.putExtra(com.lodoss.authlib.Config.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        intent.putExtra(com.lodoss.authlib.Config.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
        intent.putExtra(Config.ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
        if (AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS.equals(authTokenType))
            return AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS_LABEL;
        else if (AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY.equals(authTokenType))
            return AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY_LABEL;
        else
            return authTokenType + " (Label)";
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putBoolean(KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, false);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

So, you need to see only 2 methods: `addAccount`, `getAuthToken`.

In `addAccount` I've added some config params, which will be used by my `Activity` for User Login. The main point here is `intent.putExtra(Config.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);` - you should specify account type here. Other manipulations are not necessary.

In `getAuthToken` - **Read comments please**. I've copy-pasted this method from [UdinicAuthenticator.java](https://github.com/Udinic/AccountAuthenticator/blob/master/src/com/udinic/accounts_authenticator_example/authentication/UdinicAuthenticator.java#L46-L100)

Also, you'll be needing following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

## Summary from methods `addAccount` and `getAuthToken`

Try to get token, if token exists return result, else you will see `Activity` for authorization

2). Create `Activity` for User Login;

See [AuthenticatorActivity](https://github.com/Udinic/AccountAuthenticator/blob/master/src/com/udinic/accounts_authenticator_example/authentication/AuthenticatorActivity.java)

**Brief explanation:**
Create form with UserId and Password. Using the UserId & Password data get auth token from server and then execute the following step:

```
mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, null);
mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, authtokenType, authtoken);
```

3). Create a `Service` to communicate with account.

See [UdinicAuthenticatorService](https://github.com/Udinic/AccountAuthenticator/blob/master/src/com/udinic/accounts_authenticator_example/authentication/UdinicAuthenticatorService.java)

Don't forget to add this line in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `Service`:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
               android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
```

And also in `res/xml` add file `authenticator.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:accountType="com.mediamanagment.app"
                       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                       android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                       android:label="@string/authenticator_label"/>
```

That's all. You can use your `AccountAuthenticator`.

## For Source materials thanks to

- [Udi Cohen](https://github.com/Udinic);
- [Daniel Serdyukov](https://github.com/DanielSerdyukov)(all text translated from his article(except my
  small additions) **"Synchronization in android applications. Part 1"**
  in Russian only. link:
  http://habrahabr.ru/company/e-Legion/blog/206210/)

Comment: Excellent answer. Not only did you explain why Account Authenticator should be used, but you also went the extra mile and explained its implementation and why each step is needed.

Comment: The biggest part of my answer is Daniel's artice. Daniel, if you read it, thank you for your great article

Comment: Can I open other activity as per response.. How?

Comment: I was fighting with this for a while, having the following issue: My AddAccount() was getting called from phone settings, but the Activity wasn't started. I managed to fix it by putting the extras in the bundle passed as an argument to the method instead of creating a new Bundle.

Comment: AccountAuthenticatorActivity is deprecated as of SDK30. How will this change this overall flow?

Answer (score 8):

The `AccountManager` is good for the following reasons:

- First is to store multiple account names with different levels of access to the app’s features under a single account type. For example, in a video streaming app, one may have two account names: one with demo access to a limited number of videos and the other with full-month access to all videos. This is not the main reason for using `Accounts`, however, since you can easily manage that in your app without the need for this fancy-looking `Accounts` thing… .
- The other advantage of using `Accounts` is to get rid of the traditional authorization with username and password each time an authorized feature is requested by the user, because the authentication takes place in the background and the user is asked for their password only in certain condition, which I will get to it later.
- Using the `Accounts` feature in android also removes the need for defining one’s own account type. You have probably come across the apps using Google accounts for authorization, which saves the hassle of making a new account and remembering its credentials for the user.
- `Accounts` can be added independently through Settings → Accounts
- Cross-platform user authorization can be easily managed using `Accounts`. For example, the client can access protected material at the same time in their android device and PC without the need for recurrent logins.
- From the security point of view, using the same password in every request to the server allows for possible eavesdropping in non-secure connections. Password encryption is not sufficient here to prevent password theft.
- Finally, an important reason for using the `Accounts` feature in android is to separate the two parties involved in any business dependent on `Accounts`, so called authenticator and resource owner, without compromising the client (user)’s credentials. The terms may seem rather vague, but don’t give up until you read the following paragraph …

Let me elaborate on the latter with an example of a video streaming app. Company A is the holder of a video streaming business in contract with Company B to provide its certain members with premium streaming services. Company B employs a username and password method for recognizing its user. For Company A to recognize the premium members of B, one way would be to get the list of them from B and utilize similar username/password matching mechanism. This way, the authenticator and resource owner are the same (Company A). Apart from the users obligation to remember a second password, it is very likely that they set the same password as their Company B’s profile for using the services from A. This is obviously not favorable.

To allay the above shortcomings, OAuth was introduced. As an open standard for authorization, in the example above, OAuth demands that the authorization be done by Company B (authenticator) by issuing some token called Access Token for the eligible users (third party) and then providing Company A (resource owner) with the token. So no token means no eligibility.

I have elaborated more on this and more on `AccountManager` on my website at [here](http://www.digigene.com/android/accounts-in-android-part-one/)

Answer (score 1):

In android's settings you have accounts for your account type and from there you can add an account. AccountManager is also a central place to store credentials so you only sign in one time for each vender. If you download another google app or access an app multiple times you only enter credentials once