# Adding my app through Account Manager in android

Tags: android, android-webview, accountmanager

Basically I am working on a app that shows the content of the web using webview.But I am trying to get my app under account manager of phone's setting.As i am new to android I dont have much Idea how to do it.Any suggestion is appreciated.Please help me and deatil explaination is very much appreciated.Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364101/put-your-app-account-in-auto-sync-settings-android/35266205#35266205

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Login - Account Authenticator vs Manual Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915642/android-login-account-authenticator-vs-manual-authentication)