# Put your app account in Auto-Sync settings android

Tags: android, synchronization, contacts, accountmanager

I am new on this so i do not find the answer on the internet or i am not sure if the answer is that. What i am trying to do is to make my app sync all the contacts in the native contact app like whatsapp or facebook does. I also wanted to link contacts. Any hint or tutorial would be great.

Something like this:
[image]

What are the benefits of putting my app over there? I am very new on this. Please I hope an answer do not vote down D:. Any answer is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account Manager requires several key api's to work with your app.

**Just to show your App account**

- Authenticator Activtiy which extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator
- Service Activity which Bind's with Authenticator
- An xml file in RES/XML folder
- Some Settings in Android Manifest.

Read this 
https://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step

**To Auto Sync your Account;**

- SyncAdapter Class which extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter
- SyncService which extends Service
- an xml file , which defines metadata for SyncAdapter
- Permission in Android Manifest
- Optionally Content Provider Class

**Offical Android Developer Tutorial**
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

**Another Fully Detailed answer (With Examples) :**
[Android Login - Account Authenticator vs Manual Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915642/android-login-account-authenticator-vs-manual-authentication/31917170#31917170)