# What's AuthTokenType?

Tags: android, android-authenticator

I am trying to implement `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` but I can't get what's `authTokenType`. And what should I return in `getAuthTokenLabel()`? I read official documentation but there's poor information about `authTokenType`.
Can anyone show examples of `authTokenType` and `authTokenLabel`? How does it diff from `Account.type`?

Comment: [This May be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31917170/4168607) its a detailed answer to `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`.

Comment: @ADM I read that post, as I got from there, `authTokenType` is like `refreshToken` or `accessToken`.

Comment: @ADM but if it's so, what do I need `authTokenLabel` for?